# Synchronize Methods - Objective C

Tags: ios, restkit

I use the reskit to comsume webservice
I have the following code:

The first line: get the Token  from a web service

```
   tokenID = [self getTokenID];
```

The second line get a JSON from the same web service

```
[self sendRequest:tokenID];
```

But when execute the program.. the tokenID is not ready for the second line...
then I get the 401 error (unauthorized)

Is it possible Synchronize both methods?
For example:

When the "getTokenID" method is finished then execute the second method "sendRequest:tokenID"

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using a asynchronous call inside your getTokenID
When I look on the documentation of Restkit you should have something like this in your code:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation,     RKMappingResult *result) {
 ** CODE TO EXECUTE AFTER THE REQUEST IS FINISHED **
} failure:nil];
```

There, in the completion Block, you can get your token from the result and execute your

```
[self sendRequest:tokenID];
```

Sorry that I am so vague, but I need to see your code in getTokenID to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `[self getTokenID]` does the webservice call. I think some other code you're not showing is executing the request. When executing a request it can be asynchronous. In that case it's possible the tokenID is not ready yet when you want it to.

So my advice is: look for the code that is executing the request and find a way to hook into it to be notified when the request is finished. It could be in the form of a delegate or a block.